# handle exception in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

consider this code:

```
async function outer() {
    const inner = async () => {
        throw "xxx";
    };
    inner();
}
async function f() {
    try {
        await outer();
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
f();
```

when I run the code with node: `node myfile.js`, I will get this exception:

```
node:internal/process/promises:245
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "xxx".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

How can I modify the `f` function, so it will actually handle the exception? I specifically don't want to modify outer as this is blackbox code for me and I don't want to attach some global handler. What I want to achieve is to just modify the `f` so it actually handles the exception. Is that possible?

```
node --version
v15.14.0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise created by `inner` isn't tied, in any way, to the promise created by `outer`. `outer` will resolve before the promise created by `inner` does.

You need to `await` it.

```js
async function outer() {
    const inner = async () => {
        throw "xxx";
    };
    await inner();
}
async function f() {
    try {
        await outer();
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
f();
```

> I specifically don't want to modify outer as this is blackbox code for me

It is the only way. You can't fix a bug in `outer` without changing `outer`.